# Bluemix cloudant, when my project website started, it seems empty

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin, bluemix-app-scan

I could deploy my project on bluemix successfully, but I am not able to see any images. and it shows nothing while I am entering data in the input fields. I took project from your github and followed your steps. What could I do wrong? I will thank your help (Jeff )

Comment: Can you share the link to the GitHub project and steps  you are referring to? Also can you post any errors you see, if any?

Comment: @Klod - Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Unfortunately, your question will probably get closed because it does not meet the Stackoverflow requirements.  Please read this link then edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask